# Reasonable way to load configuration in Java (Xml/Property file)

Tags: java, xml, properties, configuration

Best practice to load configuration in Java:

1. load  configuration from Xml file.
2. load configuration from properties file

Here's my concern: Which one is the best practice?

In what scenario do we need to go for xml / properties file

Answer (score 0):

If you have  simple data, Properties are simpler and much easier to use, 
 but if you need to represent more complex date then go to xml.

You can also look at [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) which supports wide  range of formats.

Comment: can you please elaborate  with real time scenario  , if possible

Comment: Use XML when you to represent hierarchical data and use properties when you have key=values pairs